# How to perform CoreData context.count from a background thread?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Currently, the following is my implementation regarding CoreData.

```
class CoreDataStack {
    static let INSTANCE = CoreDataStack()
    
    private init() {
    }
    
    private(set) lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "xxx")
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // This is a serious fatal error. We will just simply terminate the app, rather than using error_log.
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        
        // So that when backgroundContext write to persistent store, container.viewContext will retrieve update from
        // persistent store.
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        
        return container
    }()
    
    private(set) lazy var backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let backgroundContext = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()

        backgroundContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        
        return backgroundContext
    }()
}


class NSAttachmentRepository {
    static let INSTANCE = NSAttachmentRepository()
    
    private init() {
    }
    
    func isExist(_ name: String) -> Bool {
        let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack.INSTANCE
        let viewContext = coreDataStack.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSAttachment>(entityName: "NSAttachment")
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit =  1
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", name)
        do {
            let count = try viewContext.count(for: fetchRequest)
            if count > 0 {
                return true
            }
        } catch {
            error_log(error)
        }
        
        return false
    }
}
```

My strategy dealing with core data are

1. To perform non-blocking write call from main thread (UI thread), I will use `CoreDataStack.INSTANCE.backgroundContext`
2. To perform blocking read call from main thread (UI thread), I will use `CoreDataStack.INSTANCE.persistentContainer.viewContext`

This work fine all the time, until I need to perform the following operation

- **To perform blocking read call from background thread (non UI thread)**

We need to run the code in `PHPickerViewControllerDelegate`'s `loadFileRepresentation` callback. If we check using `Thread.isMainThread` (returns false) inside `loadFileRepresentation` callback, it is executed in a background thread.

When I perform call `NSAttachmentRepository.INSTANCE.isExist(name)` in function where `Thread.isMainThread` is false, I will get the following crash

> CoreData`+[NSManagedObjectContext
> **Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor**]:

I attempt to "fix" the problem by modifying the code from using `coreDataStack.persistentContainer.viewContext` to `coreDataStack.backgroundContext`

```
func isExist(_ name: String) -> Bool {
    let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack.INSTANCE
    ////let viewContext = coreDataStack.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let backgroundContext = coreDataStack.backgroundContext
    
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSAttachment>(entityName: "NSAttachment")
    fetchRequest.fetchLimit =  1
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", name)
    do {
        ////let count = try viewContext.count(for: fetchRequest)
        let count = try backgroundContext.count(for: fetchRequest)
        if count > 0 {
            return true
        }
    } catch {
        error_log(error)
    }
    
    return false
}
```

However, I am still getting the same crash error.

Do you have any idea how I can perform CoreData context.count from a background thread?

Comment: Have you actually confirmed that writing from the main thread is a performance problem?  How much data are you writing?

Comment: Hi, we are totally fine with writing operation. Our goal is to perform read operation. The read operation is performed from an external background thread. I update my question, to explain on where the external background thread comes from.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I got it the wrong way around, but my question still stands - Is the performance a problem? Why not just dispatch the code onto the main queue if required?  Unless you are reading millions of records, Core Data is very fast.

Comment: I'm not getting the error, works fine for me. Did you try ensuring the queue by wrapping your fetch request into `backgroundContext.performAndWait(_:)`?

Comment: I think u need to enable thread debugging option https://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/

Comment: You should use `aContext.perform{}` or `aContext.performAndWait{}` to ensure that the code inside is done in the correct thread of the context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not enough to just use a background context. You need to use that context on its own queue. You checked that you're not running on the main queue, but you could be on any queue, and the background context only works on one of them. The error message you see is what Core Data says when you're using it on the wrong queue.

Any time you use `backgroundContext`, you need to wrap the code in a call to `perform` or `performAndWait`, to ensure that your code runs on the background context's queue. Since your `isExist` function is synchronous, it needs to use `performAndWait` so that it can get a result before returning.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointer from @Tom Harrington

Here's the code snippet on how to tackle such threading issue.

```
func isExist(_ name: String) -> Bool {
    let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack.INSTANCE
    let viewContext = coreDataStack.persistentContainer.viewContext
    var result = false
    
    viewContext.performAndWait {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSAttachment>(entityName: "NSAttachment")
        fetchRequest.fetchLimit =  1
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", name)
        do {
            let count = try viewContext.count(for: fetchRequest)
            if count > 0 {
                result = true
            } else {
                result = false
            }
        } catch {
            error_log(error)
        }
    }

    return result
}
```